# jqgrid autoencode=true encode postdata

Tags: jqgrid, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to fix XSS vulnerabilities across my web application and I'm stuck with jqGrid.

I activated 'autoencode' for all my grids and the documentation says : "When set to true encodes (html encode) the incoming (from server) **and posted data** (from editing modules).".

My problem is that I don't understand why posted data are encoded. This way I'm getting html escaped text in my database. So this database is no more readable by an other application (or it has to decode all texts), and in addition database search doesn't work any more.

So, is it possible to only encode data retrieved from database and post data as it ?
Currently, I disabled autoencode and added formatter on all my columns to escape all text. Is it the only way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `serializeEditData` (in case of usage [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing)), `serializeRowData` (in case of usage [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing)) or `serializeCellData` (in case of usage [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editinge)) to change the data which will be send to the server during editing. To decode the data you can use for example `$.jgrid.htmlDecode`. You can enumerate all properties of posted data and decode the value of the corresponding property. Alternatively you can use decoding of posted data on the server side. Any technology which you use on the server provide simple method which can be used for decoding. For example in ASP.NET one can use `HtmlDecode`/`HtmlEncode` methods of [HttpServerUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpserverutility_methods%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Oleg. It's working fine. But I guess it could be a nice feature to have in jqgrid.

Comment: @william: You are welcome! You can send any feature request to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/). The most problem which I see is the *compatibility* with existing code. If one would change the encoding of posted data in the next version it will break the code for all users who uses editing of grids and who uses `autoencode:true`. The users have to fix his code. So I am not sure that trirand will make the changes in the code of jqGrid.